# Difference between SharePoint App and SharePoint WebPart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013 Apps and I have following confusion.

Standard SharePoint WebPart can be added to WebPart Page and you can modify the content, appearance, and behavior of pages of a SharePoint site by using a browser...  [SharePoint WebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx)

Same way, can we do like this using SharePoint App ? means Is SharePoint App itself a WebPart? If no then how can we create a WebPart using SharePoint App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not a webpart. You add ClientWebPart to your app to make it possible to place it in a webpart zone.

[Here is a details guide how to do it with Visual Studio](http://aaronsaikovski.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/building-a-sharepoint-2013-client-web-part-using-the-client-side-object-model-csom/)